# How to find the failed requests of an WebApi which have not reached to the Webapi using Spunk or Dynatrace

Tags: splunk, dynatrace

Team, need some inputs on below query

How to find the failed requests of an WebAPI using Spunk or Dynatrace which have not reached to the WebAPI due to Infrastructure or WebAPI is down

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What does your data look like?

Comment: I have written a splunk query which pulls 500 status codes, but result didn't give which I was expecting.. so it would be great help if you could provide some direction.. to analyse further..

Comment: Please share the query, the expected results, and the actual results.

Comment: @RichG --> thank you for your response. Splunk Query : index="logs" app_name="contso"
(msg.Path="/api/cont")
| eval error_5xx=if((httpStatus>=500),1,0)
| timechart span=1w sum(error_5xx) as errCount sum(error_Not) by app_name
........
What I need --> to get a report when the API is not reachable/down to client, so that I can take precautions before the client escalates it. Any directions, How to start Analyzing through Splunk or Dynatrace.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see the raw data, but your existing query is pretty close to what you need.  One problem with it is the 'error_Not' field doesn't exist, but you may not need it.

```
index="logs" app_name="contso" (msg.Path="/api/cont") 
| eval error_5xx=if((httpStatus>=500),1,0) 
| timechart span=1w sum(error_5xx) as errCount by app_name
| where errCount > 0
```